# How to keep a Jquery slider on the right side of some text in some html table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to implement a JQuery slider next to some text and `span` in a table cell.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Transfert: <span id="Trans" /> <div id="TraSlider" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, the slider will not stick to the right or the text. It seems like `div` is the issue. I tried to change it to `span`, but the slider is not displayed properly anymore.

[image]

How can I achieve this (without moving the slider to another cell)?

**P.S.**: Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTD78/1/).

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/MTD78/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it just to be `inline-block` and with a `width`. With that in mind, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTD78/2/):

```
.ui-widget-content {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can (display: block) in the css for those cntents, but the ordering of those contents will always make a difference .
or you can try to make the slider div floated to right with CSS so the other stuff are not in affection with it's absolute place .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone beat me to it while I was fiddling. Here it is anyway. 
-- .val() works on inputs FYI.

```
// css and table width will squeeze your text so:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/MTD78/3/